# final video = await picker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.camera). In this statement variable video is null in my Flutter Project

Tags: flutter

I am developing camera app with Flutter.
In this app, this function opens camera and record video but in the end the return variable is null.
How can I resolve this?
In AndroidManifest.xml, I give camera permissions to this app like:

I am using image_picker: ^0.8.6+1, flutter: 3.10.6 channel stable, dart: 3.0.6.

how to get not empty value in pickVideo function?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.